# JQuery / Ajax Check User Messages Every 60 Seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I run a website that now features notifications and I'd like to run a script that check for new messages every 60 seconds or so.  What I need to do is pass the use id through the script to then create an alert (For now I've used a basic browser alert) but the code I have doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
JQuery

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var check;
var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;
function checkForMessages() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/check-messages.php',
        data: 'id='+ yourid,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response = 1){
                clearInterval(check);
                alert("You have mail!");
            }
            else {}
        }
    });
}
check = setInterval(checkForMessages, 60000);
};
</script>

Check Messages PHP

<?php
include("settings.php");

$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["id"]);

$check_messages_sql = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE recipient = '$yourid' AND seen = '0'";
$check_messages_res = mysqli_query($con, $check_messages_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
echo "1";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
function checkForMessages(yourid) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/check-messages.php',
        data: 'id='+ yourid,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response = 1){
                clearInterval(check);
                alert("You have mail!");
            }
            else {}
        }
    });
}
check = setInterval(checkForMessages(yourid), 60000);
```

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your function recursive, and add a 60 seconds delay :

```
function checkForMessages() {

    var dataObj = {};
    dataObj['id']= yourid;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/check-messages.php',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == 1){
                clearInterval(check);
                alert("You have mail!");
            }
            else {}
        }
    });
    setTimeout(
      function() 
      {
        checkForMessages();
      }, 1000);

}
```

This way, your function will be relaunched every 1000 ms.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not producing the Alert

Comment: I just noticed the "if(response = 1)" part, shouldn't it be "if(response == 1)" ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your syntax for the data part. Can you try again using this syntax : data: {'id': + yourid}

Comment: Well $yourid is taken from php select so I have JSON encoded it to become a variable `var yourid = <?php echo json_encode($yourid); ?>;`

Comment: Can you console_log() it and show it ? I think the issue in jour AJAX call is about the data sent.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that?

Comment: If yourid is an integer with the wanted ID, my edit may work (if the issue is with the AJAX call). 
Also : is the recipient field in your database a Varchar, or is it an Integer ?

Comment: The $yourid is 1389179019-263569923 and the recipient field is a Varchar

Comment: Is there another solution - Other code that can be used? I need this sorting out ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Try to use check as  `if(response == 1)` and set timeout as below....

```
setTimeout(function() {checkForMessages();}, 2000);
```